# C# How to set default value of a string collection in Design

Tags: c#, string, combobox, default

In WinForm, I have a combobox with DropDownStyle set to DropDownList (so can't enter a Text). In the properties window, there is the Items property which is a string collection. I enter all my values.

But now, I would like to set one of these value by default (instead to have the empty entry at run-time). I know how to do this via coding, but I am pretty sure (damn memory) that it was possible to set one of the value in the string collection as default by adding a special symbole in front of the line.

Anybody know that symbole? Or my memory is playing me trick and it is not possible to do it via the designer?

Comment: No, I thought it was that too, but it just add the & to the line

Comment: Not possible.  Assign SelectedIndex in the form constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it can be done when using a DropDownList. From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9d334c2b-ad99-4502-9f69-37bbe22fe850) it is suggested that you can set the `text` property to the default value you want, but this will only works in a DropDown rather than DropDownList style.

Comment: I know this. But I can't set it to DropDown because I do not want allowe user input. Anyway, it is not a capital problem, I know how to fix this via coding, but the question came to my mind and it really bother me that I can't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but that is not possible within the Designer only, since the `Text` property is used for this feature and that property is ignored/cleared when the using a DropDownList.

If you don't mind having your data values outside of the Designer, you could probably use DataBinding to accomplish this since the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of `ComboBox` can be used in the Designer *and* would set the display value.  I don't normally use DataBinding so unfortunately I cannot provide code examples - perhaps another user can chime in?